# How to create tile map for "Mars Miner" like game in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I need your help. I am writing a [Mars Miner](http://www.y8.com/games/mars_miner) like game in JavaFX.

I have the level generated in a two-dimensional array, and each value has a specific tile assigned to it. First, I tried a two-dimensional array of `ImageView`, but this can not be added as a child to a `Pane`. Then, I tried to render the map into `GridPane`, but will this work? I need to be able to check each `tileID` (what tile it is) and move the map, such as the when character mines down.

What is the best way of making a tile map "engine" in JavaFX that allows me to move the map with the character (or use some sort of camera), check `tileID`'s based on position, and re-render only specific tiles in the tile map?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to accomplish this with javafx. A `GridPane` is one of the options. Basically the key lays in the inputEvents. When proccesing them correctly you should be able to do everything you described above. If you are new to javafx, I would advise to read into it, or follow a few tutorials. Like: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm

Comment: Thanks, i know few basics, but still learning. Dont you know why I can not move GridPane with translateX?

Comment: Of course a `GridPane` can be moved using the translate properties. If they don't work, you've got an error somewhere else...